# Function defined within a `with` statement, but called from outside it - is Safari non-spec-compliant, or is this undefined behavior?

Tags: javascript, safari, v8, with-statement

(This question is *specifically* about whether Safari's behaviour is non-spec-compliant, and **not** "how can I fix this" or "is it a good idea to use `with` in modern JS development" or "is `with` formally deprecated". I know the answer to those questions already.)

---

The following code throws an error in Safari ("Can't find variable: foo"), but works fine in Chrome and Firefox:

```js
let obj = {foo:"bar"};
with(obj) {
  function test() {
    console.log(foo);
  }
}
test();
```

Is this a bug in Safari? Or in Chrome & Firefox? Please link me to the section of the spec which defines this if possible. Thanks!

(I guess it's also possible that the behavior of `with` was not properly specified for this sort of thing? Although it seems like a fairly simple example, so I'm guessing it's just a Safari bug.)

Comment: `with` is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with

Comment: This probably applies here: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-block-level-function-declarations-web-legacy-compatibility-semantics. tl:dr: Function declarations in blocks are weird.

Comment: I think safari either has a bug, or doesn't implement it correctly. Since it's deprecated I wouldn't be surprised this never gets fixed.